# visual composer row id not working

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to create local links on a wordpress page (anchored sections on the page) and I see that visual composer has a row ID field. I've seen examples of using that field to create link-able sections via visual composer, but when I use that row id field none of my local anchor tags work and the ID for that row in the dom(dev tools inspected) is not the one I entered in the row ID field, but instead it's an ID starting with `fws_` and then proceeded by a long string of numbers.

I have a workaround for this which is to append a raw html element to a column of that row, but that seems sloppy, I would rather use VC for this if possible. does anyone know if this `fws_******` id is some kind of conflict (I wouldn't think so since the element is generated by VC) or is VC messed up or corrupted?

Answer (score -1):

First name your row without the #hash character.

```
Row id: example
```

Then setup your div around the content you want to link (jump) to

```
<div id="example">
    content
</div>
```

Now include the row id within your link

```
http://www.example-site.com/#example
```

This is the current method I employ and works flawlessly in VC, hope this helps.

Comment: Row ID is set but still not showing in the article